# Controlling keyboard with mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, input-device

There seems to be a lot of software to control (or emulate) mouse input through the keyboard, but what about the opposite?

Basically I'm looking for a way to emulate up/down/left/right clicks with mouse movement, at a fast rate (i.e. lots of very short and quick right clicks while I move the mouse to the right)

If I have to learn some scripting language to do it, ok, but I don't know if it would even be possible.

Note: This is meant to work on fullscreen, and having a way to turn it on/off with an F# key would be awesome!

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: on what operating system?

Comment: Windows XP SP3 Pro 32bit, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, hopefully supplying a *useful* answer this time, instead of the inverse of the actual answer you wanted...

How about an AutoHotkey script for [mouse gestures](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/MouseGestures.htm)?  You haven't indicated what sort of control you require, so perhaps a set of gestures is adequate.  If, however, you're looking to essentially replace the whole keyboard with one mouse, well, this may not be the answer you need.  Or, good luck memorizing all those gestures.  :-D

---

As is so often the case, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is your tool.  I won't bore you with extensive review or details, as Google (and even SuperUser) are loaded with info about it.

EDIT: In fact, here's a [ready-made script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/NumpadMouse.htm) that'll enable you to use your numeric keypad as a mouse, with several customizations.

Comment: He's looking for the opposite.

Comment: Yes. yes he is.  I just came back here to change my answer, but you've already commented. *sigh*  Ridiculous, I even initially read the question the right-way 'round.

Comment: Also using the numpad as a mouse is possible in Windows without any special tools ... just enable MouseKeys.

Comment: @Johannes, true enough, but that (first) script I linked actually has a fairly complete mouse implementation with buttons controlling the mouse wheel and some extra buttons.  None of that matters though since he's looking for the opposite.  (Still shaking my head that I read it correctly and looked up the wrong answer anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems interesting. If AutoHotkey has mouse events this is a probable solution!

Comment: Edit: I'm so going to learn AutoHotkey! Thanks for the solution, this will take some time and effort but It's the only way to efficiently achieve my objective of sending directional keystrokes by moving the mouse. Also AutoHotkey will come in handy for doing almost anything in the future =)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, what about the On-Screen Keyboard?

It's found under **All Programs -> Accessories -> Accessibility** on XP (similar for Vista+)

[image]

Comment: Yep, assuming the O/S is a match for him, this is about the best way to go.

Comment: I knew about the on-screen keyboard, but I can use the keyboard. It would just be much better if I could use the mouse, so I'm looking for a more comfortable solution :)

Thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want something where you can type with your mouse, then I suggest you take a look at [Dasher](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/dasher/).

That is, if I take your question title as the question. As I really don't quite understand your question.

Comment: I'll take a look at Dasher =)
My intention is to control arbitrary key input through mouse movement, e.g., repeatedly emulate the input of a given "left" key while moving the mouse to the left.

Comment: Took a look at dasher, but it's not exactly what I need, I don't need all the keys in fact, just a small set of keys mapped to mouse movement. Anyway the concept of dasher is surprisingly innovattive!